# C++: const array instance generation in header file

Tags: c++, c++14

I could use a define macro to do what I want to achieve. But I'm sure there is a better way with C++14.

Basically I would like to instantiate a std::array of objets in the header of a class without defining by hand each instance.

```
    const std::array<property<uint16_t>, 16> cmd_eng1 =
    {{
            {PROG_MEM_ENG1, 0},
            {PROG_MEM_ENG1+2, 0},
            ...
            {PROG_MEM_ENG1+30, 0}
    }};
```

and if you wonder, below is the `property class` constructor (template not shown).

```
property(uint8_t addr, uint8_t bit_offset)
```

So is there a way (other than a macro) to define this array without writing everything by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Micheal's answered can be slightly improved by using a lambda instead of a function.

This is somewhat similar to the trick used to initialize a local const variable using complex logic without having to write a helper method.

```
const auto cmd_eng1 = []{
    std::array<property<std::uint16_t>, 16> result = {};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        result[i] = property<std::uint16_t>(PROG_MEM_ENG1 + 2 * i, 0);
    }

    return result;
}();
```

**Edit:** This assumes that `property` can be default-constructed.

If you cannot go through the create-then-assign sequence and have to initialize the array on construction, you have to be a little more crafty and use a variadic template, in which case, I don't think you can avoid having to write a helper function:

```
template<std::size_t... Is>
auto make_array(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
   return std::array<property<std::uint16_t>, sizeof...(Is)> {property<std::uint16_t>{PROG_MEM_ENG1 + 2 * Is, 0}...};
}

const auto cmd_eng1 = make_array(std::make_index_sequence<16>());
```

Comment: I think constexpr lambda are `C++17` feature

Comment: @Frank, thanks, this seems quite good. However, I'm getting `error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'driver_LP5562::property<short unsigned int>'`
I don't understand the problem, yet.

Comment: @Victor That's probably because `property` has no default constructor. See my ammended answer for an alternative in that case.

Comment: @Frank, indeed changing the constructor to `property(uint8_t addr=0, uint8_t bit_offset=0)` works like a charm :)

Comment: @Victor You do you in your code base, but adding a default constructor by using default values is pretty bad and error-prone. I would just add a separate default constructor instead. What if someone wrote `property(12)`?

Comment: @Frank you're totally right, I've just corrected it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this a solution to your problem?

```cpp
template<std::size_t Size>
constexpr std::array<property<std::uint16_t>, Size> makeArray()
{
    std::array<property<std::uint16_t>, Size> array = {};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
        array[i] = property<std::uint16_t>(PROG_MEM_ENG1 + 2*i, 0);
    }

    return array;
}

const auto cmd_eng1 = makeArray<16>();
```

Comment: Yes it is, thanks! However I think Frank answer is more readable (for example for another programmer reading the code), but as you pointed out, I'm not sure yet his solution can work with C++14